# What (if any) dati leumi/chardal yeshivot teach kabbalah in Israel?

Tags: yeshiva-school

I plan to go to yeshiva after the army, and I am looking for where to go.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ben. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This question is out of the scope of this site as this site is ABOUT Judaism.

Comment: @AlBerko Isn’t attending a yeshivah a part of Judaism?

Comment: @AlBerko we had this discussion once already - isn't finding the right place to learn Torah core to Judaism?

Comment: No, this is extremely subjective and temporal. This site does not give personal advice AFAIK. One can ask what Rabbis follow a certain school of learning, but what Yeshivah to go to.

Comment: @AlBerko He's not asking what yeshivah to go to. He's asking for details of which DL/Chardal yeshivot teach kabbalah.